# How to force new page if paragraph will break?

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

I am working on a project where a book gets generated from a JSON file with thousands of entries which are used as paragraphs. When I plug my code into LaTeX some paragraphs are split across two pages. I was wondering if there is a way to say something like: “If paragraph will break, move the whole of it to the next page”?

Something like `\newpage` will not be useful in my case because there are too many entries to do it by hand. I'm looking for a more programmatic solution. I have also looked at:

```
\widowpenalties 1 10000
\raggedbottom
```

But what that seems to do in my case is to just expand the text until the page is finished and not propagating the text to new page. Here a simplified version of my code with the formatting that is being used:

```
%------------------------
% Invoke Packages
%------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}

%------------------------
% Set Dimensions
%------------------------
\usepackage[ 
paperwidth = 168.3mm,
paperheight = 260.4mm,
top = 6mm,
bottom = 7mm,
outer = 6mm,
inner = 20mm
]{geometry}

%------------------------
% Remove indentation from all paragraphs
%------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Comments
\newcommand{\CommentFontSize}{21}
\newcommand{\CommentSkipMult}{25}
% Author
\newcommand{\UserFontSize}{16}
\newcommand{\UserSkipMult}{0}
% Date
\newcommand{\DateFontSize}{15}
\newcommand{\DateSkipMult}{0}

% Comments
\newenvironment{commentTextFont}{
\fontfamily{mdugm} 
\fontsize{\CommentFontSize}{\CommentSkipMult}
\selectfont}
{\par}
% Author
\newenvironment{userFont}{
\fontfamily{mdugm} 
\fontsize{\UserFontSize}{\UserSkipMult}
\selectfont}
{\par}
% Date
\newenvironment{dateFont}{
\fontfamily{mdugm} 
\fontsize{\DateFontSize}{\DateSkipMult}
\selectfont}
{\par}

%------------------------
% Set commands 
%------------------------

\newcommand{\uComment}[3]{
\begin{commentTextFont} #1 \end{commentTextFont}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{userFont} \textit{#2}
\hspace*{\fill} \begin{dateFont} #3 \end{dateFont}
\end{userFont}
\vspace*{0.8cm}
}

%------------------------
% Document
%------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\uComment{\lipsum[73]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[75]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[66]}{someone}{2000}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how this could be approached?

Comment: do all your paragraphs fit on a page and never need to break, if so it is simple, just set each paragraph in a `\parbox` if you will sometimes have a long para that needs to break, it;s harder.

Comment: Yes, they will be short or long, so sometimes will need a break, sometimes not. The solution by @egreg worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions you use are quite complicated and could be simplified, in my opinion, but the solution is anyway easy:

```
\newcommand{\uComment}[3]{%
  \filbreak
  \begin{commentTextFont}#1\end{commentTextFont}%
  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{userFont}\textit{#2}\hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{dateFont}#3\end{dateFont}\end{userFont}%
  \vspace*{0.8cm}
}
```

I used `\filbreak` before the paragraph, which means: break a page here unless a further `\filbreak` comes along and the text in between fits the page.

Here's the complete code, with all spurious spaces you insert removed.

```
%------------------------
% Invoke Packages
%------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}

%------------------------
% Set Dimensions
%------------------------
\usepackage[ 
  paperwidth = 168.3mm,
  paperheight = 260.4mm,
  top = 6mm,
  bottom = 7mm,
  outer = 6mm,
  inner = 20mm
]{geometry}

%------------------------
% Remove indentation from all paragraphs
%------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Comments
\newcommand{\CommentFontSize}{21}
\newcommand{\CommentSkipMult}{25}
% Author
\newcommand{\UserFontSize}{16}
\newcommand{\UserSkipMult}{0}
% Date
\newcommand{\DateFontSize}{15}
\newcommand{\DateSkipMult}{0}

% Comments
\newenvironment{commentTextFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\CommentFontSize}{\CommentSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}
% Author
\newenvironment{userFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\UserFontSize}{\UserSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}
% Date
\newenvironment{dateFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\DateFontSize}{\DateSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}

%------------------------
% Set commands 
%------------------------

\newcommand{\uComment}[3]{%
  \filbreak
  \begin{commentTextFont}#1\end{commentTextFont}%
  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{userFont}\textit{#2}\hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{dateFont}#3\end{dateFont}\end{userFont}%
  \vspace*{0.8cm}
}

%------------------------
% Document
%------------------------

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\uComment{\lipsum[73]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[75]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[66]}{someone}{2000}

\end{document}
```

A picture of the page break.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot, this works out perfectly and it was so simple. Sorry for the weird environment definitions, I have built it like this because the code is for a designer that will most likely define a new font/fontsize for every item, so I had to think of a way to modularise it all. I am wondering... would there be any way of instead of moving the paragraph to a new page, removing it from the final text?